# Getting my AWS credentials using an API call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have a node app that listens for messages on a RabbitMQ queue, and for each message it receives, it launches a new independent node process that goes to work on the content of the message.

This second, launched-on-demand node app does some work with S3, taking its credentials from the IAM role of the box.

It turns out that I seem to be hit by a bug in the retrieval of the IAM role by the Node AWS SDK through the EC2 metadata service.  Basically, under load, the http call to the metadata service times out (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/692).

So as a workaround, I am wondering if the parent node process can somehow retrieve AWS credentials using some API call or other trickery, and pass them on the command line to the child node app?

This would mean only one call to the metadata service by the parent app, reducing the load on it.

Possible in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the main node app retrieve the credentials from the metadata service, cache them locally in memory, pass them as needed when invoking the child processes, and have the main node app refresh the cached credentials just before they expire.

You can retrieve the access key ID, secret access key, session token, and expiration time directly from the metadata service. For example: `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/role-xyz` will yield:

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2016-01-15T16:20:09Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "xxx",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "xxx",
  "Token" : "xxx",
  "Expiration" : "2016-01-15T23:00:11Z"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of thing I was thinking.  As the child process could potentially be long running, what happens if it continues to make S3 multipart upload http calls after 2016-01-15T23:00:11Z - using the JSON from your answer?

Comment: @MikeHogan If the uploader client makes any API call with expired credentials then that API call will be rejected with ExpiredToken. I think you will need to ensure that your upload completes before the temporary credentials expire, or get new temporary credentials to use with all API calls made after the original set expire. I think that should work, but have not actually tested it. If you are using an IAM role on an EC2 instance then I'd expect this to be handled for you under the covers by the SDK in combination with the EC2 metadata service, but again have not tested this.

Comment: Where does the IP address 169.254.169.254 come from?

Comment: @LRK9 169.254.169.254 is a link-local address used by some cloud vendors on their VMs to expose a metadata server. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address and http://serverfault.com/questions/427018/what-is-this-ip-address-169-254-169-254.

Comment: Why does it timeout when I try to use it on my EC2 instance? What sort of VM would I launch?

Comment: Does visiting http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ time out? If you reboot, does it work?