# AWS Retrieving Security Credentials from Instance Metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

This is not a duplicate of the question [Getting my AWS credentials using an API call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34810642/850848), because I am asking specifically about what Amazon means in the example that they give.

I am looking here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

I see this bit:

> **Warning**
>
> If you use services that use instance metadata with IAM roles, ensure that you don't expose your credentials when the services make HTTP calls on your behalf. The types of services that could expose your credentials include HTTP proxies, HTML/CSS validator services, and XML processors that support XML inclusion.
>
> The following command retrieves the security credentials for an IAM role named `s3access`.
>
> ```
> $ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3access
> ```

Where does this IP address come from? What is 169.254.169.254? It can't be my server, since I don't have software running on port 80, nor would I grant Amazon an alias on my server.

But I did actually run the above, and it simply timed out. So the IP address 169.254.169.254 is not a service that Amazon is actively running. So what is it?

Does anyone understand this example that Amazon offers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`169.254.169.254` is the address of the AWS metadata service. You can query this address from an EC2 server to obtain information about the server. The metadata that can be obtained in this manner is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html).

Are you saying that when you run that `curl` command from an EC2 server it is timing out?

Answer (score 24):

169.254 is within the link-local address space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address

It's usually used for a lot of localhost/local-subnet use cases. Amazon happens to put their metadata service at 169.254.169.254 so that it can be queried from EC2 Instances.

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data`

Should always return something, the full `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/s3access` will only return something if you had an IAM role attached to your instance named `s3access`.

Comment: this is the most clear post showing how to do that : https://rhynorater.github.io/AWS-Metadata-Identity-Credentials